# Write Linux Disk Image to SD card

Tags: linux, formatting, sd-card, format

Like the title says:
I am trying to write a Linux Image to an SD card. Originally I had Linux working fine and would boot on my FPGA. However, when I tried to load a `.py` file, it corrupted the SD card and when I tried to boot, it would display random characters.

I've tried reformatting the SD card with Windows reformat and SD Card Formatter (quick format and regular). I've tried flashing the image with the Win32 disk imager and also etcher. When I flash the image, it says successful, but when I attempt to boot nothing happens and no files or image appears in the SD directories.

So my question is:
is the SD card able to still be written onto or is it corrupted and I need to get a new one?

Comment: I would suggest getting a new one.